# How can I query the albums with MediaBrowser?

Tags: android, media

I guess it has to do something with the onLoadChildren method, but I have no idea how to get the albums, song or artists via MediaBrowser.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a service that extends [`MediaBrowserService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService.html), you can retrieve any metadata in [`onLoadChildren`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService.html#onLoadChildren(java.lang.String,%20android.service.media.MediaBrowserService.Result%3Cjava.util.List%3Candroid.media.browse.MediaBrowser.MediaItem%3E%3E)).

In your onLoadChildren you should use [`MediaMetadata`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadata.html):

> Contains metadata about an item, such as the title, artist, etc.

From which you can retrieve things like artist, title, etc, using [`MediaDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDescription.html):

> A simple set of metadata for a media item suitable for display.

```
@Override
public void onLoadChildren(final String parentMediaId, final Result<List<MediaItem>> result) {
  for (MediaMetadata track : mMusicProvider.getMusicsByGenre(genre)) {
      // once you have an instance of MediaMetadata, you can retrieve any data you want:
      MediaDescription simpleData = track.getDescription();
      // or retrieving with a key from its info Bundle:
      // android.media.metadata.MEDIA_ID
      // android.media.metadata.TRACK_NUMBER
      // android.media.metadata.ALBUM
      // android.media.metadata.GENRE
      // android.media.metadata.TITLE
      // android.media.metadata.ARTIST
      // android.media.metadata.NUM_TRACKS
      // android.media.metadata.DURATION
      // android.media.metadata.ALBUM_ART_URI
      track.getString( ... );
  }
}
```

### You can see a clearer implementation of this in [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService).

Comment: This part is clear, but I don't know how to get the genres, albums, artists from the device. Shall I use MediaStorage to get and store the items and when I have to access them, use the "MusicProvider" to get a list of the songs (e.g) a specific album contains?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to retrieve detail from media file

For Example:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
metaRetriver.setDataSource("/sdcard/audio.mp3");

String artist= metaRetriver .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
Strng genre = metaRetriver .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing in my app, where I wanted to show the existing songs on the device. My service does return the items at the onLoadChildren() method, and I return the items in a paginated way, so we fetch only the items the user is interested to see. I did it using Android's new [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/). I go over it in much greater details in a [post](https://medium.com/@shevach/how-to-paginate-mediabrowserservice-e4fdc902ff2) I wrote, where I also demonstrate the solution using code samples. Hope it helps.